# Can the sentence that comes after "comma + as" equal in meaning to the word before the comma?

Tags: commas

"This time of social change also saw an artistic revolution, as the impressionist movement arose to challenge the conventions of art"

I always learned that "as" was a word that meant that two things were happening at the same time. In this case, the author is saying that the "impressionist movement arose to challenge" = artistic revolution. I have never heard of "as" being used this way. Can anyone very that this is correct? It appears to me that a semicolon should replace "comma + as".

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence "*this time of social change also saw an artistic revolution, as the impressionist movement arose to challenge the conventions of art*" the word 'as' does not necessarily imply that the two  events "were happening at the same time" though you could chose to interpret it that way, if you were very particular. Nor does it need to imply "equal in meaning" as you seem to understand it.

Please remember that 'as' in a sentence has a wide variety of meanings, including 'because' as in

> he ran to the bus stop **as** he was late for school
>
> she ignored his messages **as** she didn't like him.

Many textbooks also mention that 'as' can be an ambiguous term that may need to be understood in the context of the sentence.

I THINK 'AS' in the sentence you have quoted seems to suggest either an explanation or a cause and effect relationship.

This is the way I would break the sentence down for interpretation:

> "This time of social change also saw an artistic revolution..." **HOW** *did it occur?* (by what process?) "**as** the impressionist movement arose to challenge the conventions of art"
>
> here 'as' proceeds to describe how (the process by which) the first event occurred -- it can be considered an *explanation* of the event.

Option 2:

> "This time of social change also saw an artistic revolution..." **WHY** *did it occur?* "**as** (because) the impressionist movement arose to challenge the conventions of art"
> NOTE: here 'as' is used to mean 'because' and gives the *reason* for the event.

Now if 'as' were to mean 'at the same time as' here, then the sentence would mean

> this time of social change also saw an artistic revolution; **at the same time** the impressionist movement arose to challenge the conventions of art

but that does not seem the intended meaning.

On the other hand, if 'as' implied 'equal in meaning' as you understand it, the meaning of the sentence would become

> "This time of social change also saw an artistic revolution; **this is equal in meaning to saying that** the impressionist movement arose to challenge the conventions of art"

However, if you read the sentence carefully, it is not exactly 'equal in meaning' but more of an **explanation** for the event.

THE CLUE FOR YOU is *'arose to challenge'* in the second part of the sentence which corresponds strongly with the meaning of the word *'revolution'* in the first part, thus suggesting that 'as' here indicates **why** (the *reason*) or **how** (the *process by which*) the event occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If the author meant *the impressionist movement arose to challenge = artistic revolution* then it should have been *just as*.

*As* by itself often conveys *at the same time* yet consider how the same could sometimes be *as* true for *just as*…

Please also consider how slight a difference there is between any of that and, for instance the rather strange *I always learned* as opposed to the more usual *I learned* or *I was always taught*.

Comment: Tragically the question was asked many days ago and nobody addressed it at the time, not even in comments. Why not, I wonder! YOU AND I may well have answered a question for which OP has found a solution long back, though certainly not from anybody's response here. Not that I ever consider my time wasted, but still I must remember to note the question date before writing a detailed answer that might possibly benefit not OP directly but only future readers!

Comment: I guess you're right… When I first joined, the forum notes suggested starting a while back and looking mostly at unanswered questions, which I'm still largely trying to catch up with!

Comment: It is a good thing of course, because it gives us good practice in composing proper answers to possibly difficult questions -- the problem is that OP might be long gone if they are not regular members,  and the only beneficiaries are future readers... Having said that, the long term goal of Stack Exchange websites is to build up a vast archive of good questions and proper answers for the benefit of future readers!